# Windows Explorer view settings for a particular subtree

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, default-settings

From the "**Folder Option**" menu in Windows Explorer, I changed the default view for all folders to be Large Icons. As far as it goes, I am happy with it.

[image: setting]

What I want to do now is, selectively use "Details" or "List" view for all directories inside

- C:\Windows | List view
- C:\Program Files (and (x86)) | List view
- C:\MingW | Details view

Is there some way to change the default view settings for the directory tree above while keeping the default view to be *Large Icon*?

Answer (score -1):

What I have seen in this regard is as follows. I simply copied it and used it, so take it with a (block) grain of salt. I hope it does what you want.

=====

## My Original Find: [Windows registry entries for default explorer view](https://superuser.com/questions/253249/windows-registry-entries-for-default-explorer-view)

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams

"Settings"=hex:08,00,00,00,04,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,77,7e,13,73,35,cf,11,ae,\ 69,08,00,2b,2e,12,62,04,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,43,00,00,00

However, as you can see the data is in an [i]ncomprehensible format. The fifth hexadecimal value, "04" in my example, indicates the display style setting. Possible values:

01: Large Icons

02: Small Icons

03: List View

04: Details

=====
Other Sources of Information https://msfn.org/board/topic/30481-registry-entry-view-details-in-windows-explorer/