# Bulk folder view modification

Tags: windows-xp, bulk

Right-click --> View --> Thumbnails

How to do this simple task for a **folder and all its sub-folders** at once in Windows XP (and possibly later Windows versions).

Comment: @miroxlav This applies the current folder view settings to ALL folders. That's not what I'm looking for. Did you try reading my question a bit more carefully?

Answer (score 0):

#### I think it can be achieved only by custom script/tool.

There is [similar question for Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/849943/windows-explorer-view-settings-for-a-particular-subtree) currently also without an answer.

Personally from what I see **I doubt that setting view for subfolders was made possible in Windows.**

Maybe if you have programming skills, you can

1. analyze (using [ProcessMonitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx)) which Registry key is set when you change settings for current folder and then
2. create a tool which copies settings for current folder into settings of each of its subfolders (by creating/modifying appropriate Registry keys).

If you wonder whether someone has already written such a tool, you can search/ask at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site.